# SwapChainPanel DPI Awareness

Tags: winapi, winui-3

My app has a swap chain to draw, either directly to a `HWND` or, in the WinUI3 version, a `SwapChainPanel`.

When the DPI Awareness setting is lacking from the App Manifest, everything is fine:

```xml
<dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitorV2</dpiAwareness>
```

My DPI is always 96 and Windows scales appropriately.

When my app is DPI-aware, and I put it on a 4K screen that has a 150% scaling with a DPI of 144, the normal Win32 version of my app runs correctly. I get a `GetClientRect` of 4K, my Direct2D `SwapChain` size is also 3840x2160.

When I run the WinUI version with the `SwapChainPanel`, a weird thing is seen. I still get a Direct2D `SwapChain` of 3840x2160, but the `SwapChainPanel` resizes off the screen, so the far right and the far bottom of my content cannot be seen. The Direct2D code sees the normal rect of 3840x2160, but drawing to the bottom area of this rect isn't shown.

If I set the DPI Awarename to `"PerMonitor"` instead of `"PerMonitorV2"`, it works correctly.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Have you tried the latest WinUI3 (1.5)? It seems things have changed in this area, I have code that needed some custom code for proper hiDPI handling with PerMonitorV2 and now it works w/o doing anything (I actually need to remove that code that I'm pretty sure was needed sometimes ago)... You can also check SwapChainPanel CompositionScaleX/Y properties vs Content.XamlRoot.RasterizationScale see if there's anything funky

Comment: @SimonMourier I updated to WinUI3 1.5 and it still has the same issue. The workaround is [here](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/8219) as indicated in the answer. It's weird, though, to have this behaviour by design.

Comment: Ok then, but it's strange because that's actually what I used to do before and now it seems this has changed (in certain ways)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refer to the thread:https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/8219

Accoridng to the Doc:[SwapChainPanel Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.swapchainpanel?view=windows-app-sdk-1.4#remarks)

> In order to maintain crisp vector rendering, you should listen for the
> CompositionScaleChanged event and query the CompositionScaleX and
> CompositionScaleY property values to account for the current UI scale,
> and potentially render again from DirectX. Otherwise XAML layout might
> do the scaling and your visuals might be degraded.

This is currently as designed.